# Visual Studioでブレークポイントをセットしてデバッグ後、Load Symbols for... で止まってしまう。

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net

Visual Studioでブレークポイントをセットしてデバッグしようとしたら、Load Symbols for...で止まってしまいます。一時間ほど待ってみましたが、結局状況は何も変わりませんでした。

.NET 4.0までは、同様の問題を下記の手順で解消していました。

1. ソリューションファイル.suoを削除
2. 関連するTEMPファイルを削除
   `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`
   `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0`
3. web.configにてDebugが有効であることを確認
4. ソリューションをクリーンにし、ツールオプションにある"Enable Just My Code"のチェックを外す
5. IISRESET

今回は.NET 4.5ですので、バージョンが関連しているかどうかわかりませんが、同じくデバッグがLoad Assembliesで止まってしまった方はいませんか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> **更新**：
>   上記の手順１－５まで行い、IISにてサイトを削除しました。別のサイト名で再度サイトを作成して、通常とおりでブレークポイントをセットしてデバックするとシンポルが通常のようにロードされました。とりあえず、問題が”解決”、作業が続けますが。理由はわかりません。おそらくTEMPファイルがどこかにあってそれが削除されていないかもしれません。

Comment: デバッグ＞全てのブレークポイントを削除 してからならどうでしょうか？

Comment: 全てのブレークポイントを削除して、同じ結果でした。